# WebUser Control Updating Parent Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender, webusercontrol

I have a page where a user will input some values.  There is a Label which holds values for options (i.e.  Timezone).  User clicks on the linkbutton and a Web User Control displays via AJAX ModalPopupExtender.

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeOptions" runat="server" TargetControlID="lbError" DropShadow="True" CancelControlID="Options1$lbCancelHelp" OkControlID="Options1$butOK" PopupControlID="pnlOptions" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlOptions" runat="server" CssClass="GridView" Width="400px">
    <oc1:Options ID="Options1" runat="Server" />        
</asp:Panel>
```

User makes their choice in the popup. Clicks OK and the popup closes.  However the Label doesn't update with the user's selection.  It only updates if you click on Options again.

I added a PostCallback in the butOK on the popup:

```
ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
        if (sm != null)
            sm.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(butOK);
```

And in the Form Load added:

```
lblTimezone.Text = "Timezone: " + Options1.TimeZone.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Comment: I've also tried to not include the OKControlID, but when I click OK, nothing happens.  This is a loaded ascx page so the form isn't build on the parent page.

Comment: Is you `Label` placed inside `UpdatePanel` with `Condition=Always`?

Comment: I hadn't, but I just tried and nothing changed.  It only populates when I click on the link again to open the popup.  Also where do I put Condition=Always?  Didn't see that option available.